# How to create docker images for a system with multiple applications

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have installed and configured a system in EC2s using Ansible. It is 1 EC2 master with a few EC2 workers. Sometimes when I use ansible to update or reinstall configuration, it fails because either some package has been removed from open-source repositories, or the package is updated so not compatible with some other packages. And I learned that using docker-container can resolve these kind of configuration problems.

However, according to what I learned, each docker image will create image of one application (I guess one application means one process). But mine is a system which has airflow master webserver, airflow worker webserver, flower webserver, rabbitmq, airflow celery, several configuration files, etc. how can I create docker images for that? Should I create one docker image for each process? How do I know which linux folder should I go to create each docker image? How do I know which applications/processes I need to create? And how to combine these images to make them work together as a system?

Or maybe in my case I should not use docker image, Instead I should just create an EC2 image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use docker-compose.

> Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

> each docker image will create image of one application (I guess one application means one process)

That is basically correct. You should create one docker-container per application. In theory you can have multiple process per container, but that doesn't matter in this case.

> how can I create docker images for that?

In your case you should make one docker-container for airflow master webserver, one for airflow worker webserver, one for flower webserver, etc. And the you use a docker-compose.yml to link them all together.

> Should I create one docker image for each process?

generally yes. (It may depend on your exact setup though)

> And how to combine these images to make them work together as a system?

docker-compose.

> How do I know which linux folder should I go to create each docker image?

I don't understand that question

> How do I know which applications/processes I need to create?

You could create a deployment-diagram and then start from there.

Comment: Thanks, I am docker beginner I will read docker-composer then I will have the answers of all the above questions.

Comment: @user389955 a little heads up: docker + docker-compose is quite complicated to get into. It will take a couple of weeks until you have the first usable results. But it's worth it.

Comment: @watanii I feel that. but I heard it is popular and useful will try.